# Kendo UI Scheduler ASP.NET MVC implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to implement the Scheduler from Kendo UI web into my ASP.NET MVC4 application, i've followed this tutorial: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4

but I have some troubles like:

- I had to add the dll file:  **Kendo.Mvc.dll** which was missing from my (open source/free) download of Kendo UI Web
- When using **@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))** , I get an error : *Error 2 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type* 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added everything: namespaces, web config, scripts, js files,... So i don't get what i'm doing wrong...

I just want to implement the open source scheduler from Kendo into my MVC .NET application, anybody any idea's on how to accomplish this?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your web.config file. You should add missing namespaces like this:

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
  </namespaces>
```